# me gustaría traducir este código en ensamblador RISC-V

Tags: ensamblador

necesito traducir este codigo en c a ensamblador risc- v
son varias matrices con comparaciones, las declaraciones ya estan hechas anteriormente

```
int main() {
int a;
float b,c;
b=B[0];
c=B[1];
for (a=0;a<5;a++) {
  b=b+W[0][j]*X[a];
  c=c+W[1][j]*X[a];
}
if (b> U[0]) 
    Y[0] = b;
else Y[0] = 0;
if (c> U[1]) 
    Y[1] = c;
else Y[1] = 0;

return 0;
}
```

---

he hecho así las declaraciones

```
.data
W: 0.3,0.45,1.2,6.8,3.2,1.1,0.8,2.2,1.5,0.68
B: 0.3,1.1
U: 2.3,3.8
X: 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
Y: 0.0,0.0
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento, y el problema _específico_ que has tenido. Lee [ask].

Comment: No somos traductores. Ese es el propósito del compilador. Compila del código y usa algún comando como `objdump` o https://godbolt.org/

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/vcc9bedvK Por cierto el código tiene errores.

Comment: @Mateo, saltan errores de declaración, ya que en esa parte no están definidas

Comment: @ImSilent bueno, que las defina cómo deba hacerlo. No podemos adivinar.